# Making 2 divs from different places have the same height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 different divs to create my home slideshow banner. The one containing the banner content is called #flex-viewport. Behind that I have a wave video in a div #video-container.

The #flex-viewport div is inside the page container to make it centered, but the #video-container is in a different container div to make it fill the entire width of the screen.

I'm not quite sure how to make these both the same height. If you visit my URL, you will see the problem. glymed-plus.mybigcommerce.com

I'm not sure if I need a javascript solution or how to fix this problem. The divs aren't floating, and they don't need to look like columns. Those are the only solutions I could find, and I couldn't get it to work. This does need to be responsive.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I can't quite tell what it is you want when I go to your site. Do the divs have different heights and different distances from the top of the screen?

Comment: you can use javascript to read the height of one container and set the other one to the same height

Comment: `var height = document.getElementById('#flex-viewport').attr('height');  document.getElementById('#video-container').attr('height') = height;`    Or something like that. I forget

Comment: I want the video to be the same height as the slideshow.

Comment: Do you want the video under the slideshow? I know you're not asking about design but that makes my head twirl.

Comment: Try setting the height like I showed above, but change the height of your video element, not the #video-container.  This and taking away width: 100% on the video makes it work.

Comment: I want the video of the swirl to loop behind the slideshow so that it is a seamless effect when the slideshow gets changed or anything gets added I don't have to code and recreate an entire video/slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what you want (which is my best understanding after reading all the comments plus your post), I would use javascript:

```
function sameHeight() {
    document.getElementById("flex-viewport").style.height = document.getElementById("video-container").style.height = '500px'; //pick a number, I picked 500 here
}
```

jQuery can also be used:

```
function sameHeight() {
    $("#flex-viewport, #video-container").height(num); //pick a number
}
```

You would trigger this with an onload or other event, for example, onload of `<body>`

```
<body onload="sameHeight()">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing it correctly? It looks like there is a flash when the page loads, and then it goes back to what I don't want.

Comment: Do you have an external javascript file or are you placing the function in the head? If the function is in the <head> of your document you need an opening <script> tag and a closing tag </script>. Also, if you use the jQuery solution you need to load jQuery first...I use <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> in the <head> of the document

Comment: Also, when I "view source" for your site I don't see any element with an id #flex-viewport...the id's would need to match in the html and javascript